# but how do the constructor work?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class A{
public:
    A(){cout << "A()" << endl; }
    A(string s): str(s){ cout << "A(" << str << ")" << endl; }
    ~A(){ cout << "delete!" << endl;}
    string str = "000";
};
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //A a0;    // it will call A() by default
    A a1();    //even if i comment A(), the compiler will no warn me anything
    A a2("123");
    cout << a2.x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
A(123)
123
delete!
```

so, i just want to know why "A a1();" can't works? can someone helps me ? thank you!

Comment: You misspelled `<iostream>`, and `A(string s)` refers to a nonexistent `x` variable.  Please post your actual code.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate, but that's not really the right question to link to.

Comment: @JamesCurran If you've got a better one you can reopen it (and then close again, I think).

Comment: [Turn up your warning level](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2823639134892991) (I fixed `iostram`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A a1(); is a function prototype, taking no parameters and returning an A

Comment: Whoever downvoted this: Most Vexing Parse. Look it up.

Comment: How about int a (5);

Comment: `int a(5);` cannot be a function declaration, and therefore must be a variable definition, specifically the equivalent of `int a = 5;`

Comment: Oh, I see now. But is declaring functions inside other functions even legal? Excluding lambdas obviously...

Comment: @ventsyv Declaring is legal, defining isn't.